# Google Maps en Flutter no me habilita options: GoogleMapOptions

Tags: flutter

Por que puede ser que me marque error en options:

```
 Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {},
          options: GoogleMapOptions(
            cameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462),
            ),
          ),),
      )
```

En pubspec.yaml

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter:
      git:
        url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins
        path: packages/google_maps_flutter
```

Y después habilite los permisos en Android como en Ios.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchos cambios en ese package debido a que es developer preview aún, al parecer ya removieron ese Widget( o al menos lo hicieron private) intenta con esto :

```
    GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {},
          initialCameraPosition:    CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462),
            ),

          ,),
```

Comment: Diego, anda perfecto así, y que atributos les puedo pasar para marcar esas coordenadas? xq solamente me hace focus

Comment: Y como seria para saber localización del usuario y mandarlo también a dichas coordenadas

Comment: Tendrías que usar algún plugin de geolocalización , obtener la ubicación y pasarle esos valores a tu googlemap widget.
Para marcar las coordenadas supongo que puedes usar Markers

Comment: Por cierto , si mi respuesta responde tu pregunta inicial, puedes marcarla como resuelta :)